# Why is FB.UI Share response returning nothing?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, share, facebook-share, fb.ui

I have setup a share popup triggered by Jquery. It works, but I want to use the response value to trigger an AJAX call on success and Facebook only returns an empty array.

Here is the javascript

```
    $("#fb-request").click(function () {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'share',
            name: 'Check out website',
            href: 'URL_TO_SHARE',
        },
        function (response) {
            if (response && !response.error_code) {
              console.log(response); // Returns: []
            }
        });
    });
```

Because of this I can't make the difference between someone who posts and someone who uses the cancel button. Am I missing something here?
Or is there something to setup on the Facebook App?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

From [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#response):

> Response Data
>
> Parameter Description
> object_id
> Only available if the user is logged into your app using Facebook and has granted publish_actions. If  present, this is the ID of the published Open Graph story.

Comment: Ok, i login user on background with FB.login but this doesn't help, i still get the empty response

Comment: You should provide login with access permissions, it is made like that:  
  `function myFacebookLogin() {  
    FB.login(function(){}, {scope: 'publish_actions'});  
  }`

Comment: i also facing same problem, even though i got user logged in with same as described in above comment.

Comment: And what will happen now that publish_actions is not available?

Comment: Same problem here even if he user is logged in!! any solution?

Answer (score 2):

If the user cancels the share dialog, the response is undefined, so:

```
$("#fb-request").click(function () {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        name: 'Check out website',
        href: 'URL_TO_SHARE',
    },
    function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error_code) {
            if (typeof response != 'undefined'){
                //shered
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This code works fine in PC / Android, but it doesn't work on iOS.
As long as the user is not logged in to your app (with the proper permission), the value of response will always be an empty array (regardless if the share has happened or not).

Answer (score 0):

Check first if your user is connected.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.status === 'connected') {
    FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'feed',
            link: 'your_url',
            mobile_iframe: true
        },
        function(response){
        });
}
else {
    FB.login(function(response){
        FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'feed',
            link: 'your_url',
            mobile_iframe: true
        },
        function(response){
        });
    });
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    display: 'popup',
    href: url,
}, function(response){
    if (typeof response != 'undefined'){
        alert("shared");
    }else{
        alert("no shared");
    }
});
```